# How to make a blog tab in every user profile

Tags: users, nodes

I have enabled the Blog module in order to have a blog for every user. Now I want to create a tab in each user profile that it links to that user's blog.

Is it possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this by either using the Views module or the Page manager module, without any custom coding:

- With the Views module, you could create a list of all blog posts by a user, and display that as a tab on the user's page. However, it would not be *the same* list as the one the Blog module creates (though it could look the same). A guide for using Views can be found here: http://nodeone.se/blogg/learn-views-with-nodeone-part-1-overview – in particular check out episode 21 for this use case.
- With the Page manager module, you could create a tab that redirects to the blog list page for that user. However, the visitor would end up on the blog list page – which *does not* have tabs for returning to the previous page. See [Learn Page manager!](http://nodeone.se/blogg/learn-page-manager-screencast-series-summed-up) for an introduction to this module.

In general, I would recommend that you build your own blog using custom content types and the Views module – it will give you more flexibility in the long run.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I used page manager and managed to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom module, you can implement `hook_menu()` in the following way:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['user/%user/blog'] = array(
    'title' => 'My blog', 
    'page callback' => 'blog_page_user', 
    'page arguments' => array(1), 
    'access callback' => 'blog_page_user_access', 
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'blog'), 
    'file' => 'blog.pages.inc',
  );

  return $items;
}
```

The "file path" property is used because the module that defines the menu is not the one containing the "blog.pages.inc" file.

If you have few experience on how to create a Drupal module, you should start looking at:

- [Creating Our First Module using Drupal 6 (Part1)](http://www.packtpub.com/article/creating-our-first-module-using-drupal6-part1)
- [Creating a Simple Drupal Module](http://geeksandgod.com/tutorials/computers/cms/drupal/creating-simple-drupal-module)
- [Creating Drupal 6.x modules](http://drupal.org/node/231276)
- [Creating Drupal 7.x modules](http://drupal.org/node/361112)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As a beginner to php and Drupal i tried to follow your instructions but i couldn't make them work. I created a folder in sites/all/module named blog_help. There i put a blog_help.info and a blog_help.module file containing your code(i changed mymodule). I enabled the module, cleared the cache but with no result. I use Drupal 6.x and to create the user profile i use the user%user panel page.

Comment: I added some links that could help you to write a module.